# python hash string into location in file

Tags: python, hash

Is there a way to use hash function (or something similar) to generate a unique location in a file, so that I can easily retrieve certain values corresponding to this string from this location:

```
>>> hash('abs')
-1600925517
>>> hash('cv')
-1537434339
>>> hash(112)
112
>>> hash('ANNC')
258026172
>>> hash('annc')
1415313084
>>> hash('an')
-1549758577
>>> hash('anc')
-1588925561
>>> hash('abs')
-1600925517
```

so that it would be something like

```
def hash_location(string):
   return location

open_file=open(file_path,'r+')
our_string='something'
location=hash_location(our_string)
open_file.seek(location)
open_file.write(our_string)
open_file.close()
```

so that the hash values can correspond to some "positive" location on file that I can just compute given only the string

Comment: Why do you think that this way would be a better one than using rgexes ?

Comment: Even without regexes, it is possible to locate strings in a file using string method ``find`` that is extremely fast.

Comment: guys, I am talking about very large list of strings (10M+) that I want to store physically on file, can't use regex for that... I need a function that I can feed the string to it and it would give me an integer that reflects the unique location associated with it

Comment: You're probably best off using gdbm or bsddb.  These are single-table databases that have been in Python a very long time.  They're usage is quite simple - they look like a dictionary that you put strings in.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import random
from hashlib import sha1

file_ext = ".jpg"
unique_filename = sha1(str(random()).hexdigest() + file_ext
```

Comment: but this actually generates a random file name... I want something like the hash function to generate everytime an integer that is unique to each string so that I can use it to locate this string within a large file

Comment: @hmghaly I think the intention here is to replace str(random()) with your actual strings. However given you stated that you have 10M+ strings, you might need to use a directory structure. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

No - `hash` on my platform returns at least a 64-bit number, so even if you were only storing strings of length 1 byte, you would still need 2**64 = 16 exbibytes of disk space.

What is the specific problem you are trying to solve? There are probably better ways to accomplish your goals.

**EDIT**

Given your requirement of storing 10M+ strings, I would suggest something like the following https://serverfault.com/a/95454/98153

Use a well defined hashing algorithm such as MD5 rather than the built in `hash` function in Python which may vary by platform or implementation.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5('test').hexdigest()
'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'
```

Then take 3 characters at a time to form a directory structure - this gives a max of 16*16*16 = 4096 files per directory. So in the above example, you would use

```
/098/f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6.txt
```

Depending on your string length, storing the strings in individual files may not be efficient due to block filesystem storage. So at this stage you could just store one string per line in a file, and do a search on the (very small) file, eg:

```
/908/f6b.txt contains:
cd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 test
02ab5595859014ebf0951522d9 another string
```

You may need to adjust the parameters to your specific application, but this seems like a good starting point.

Comment: I have something like 10M+ strings that I want to store in a file, and I want to find a function like hash function that can give me a uniue integer for each string that I can use to locate the string on the file instead of having to go across it line by line or having to store it in the RAM

Comment: You could use a 32bit hash function, which would require only 4GB per byte of your max string length - but this would increase the chance of a collision. Why reinvent the wheel though? Databases and filesystems probably handle this already.

Comment: I think the dbs are standard solution for that, but I was wondering whether there is an alternative for that with such function